# Start Phoenix app with cowboy server on different port

Tags: cowboy, phoenix-framework

Is it possible to start locally a few Phoenix apps on different ports from the console using some command like `mix phoenix.server --port=4001`? This one does not work, of course, but, maybe, there is similar way.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yep! Make sure you set the mix config to reference the env port, i.e.

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
```

Then from the terminal:

```
$ PORT=4001 mix phoenix.server
$ PORT=4002 mix phoenix.server
$ PORT=4003 mix phoenix.server
```

Comment: Note: Doing this in `config.exs` does not work, the reason I guess is the `dev.exs` overrides the config. Hence put this in `dev.exs`. For more info see this issue on phoenix https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/962

Comment: Note 2: You shouldn't add the lines to your config files but edit the existing lines. I got a cryptic error by just adding the lines for my app.

Answer (score 41):

Edit your `config/dev.exs` and change the Endpoint http port like the following:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: System.get_env("PORT") || 4000],
```

This allows the port to be set, or left as the default `4000`:

```
PORT=4002 mix phoenix.server # to run on port 4002
mix phoenix.server # to run on port 4000
```

This answer was described by @chris-mccord [on github](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/962).

Comment: This worked. The command to start Phoenix is now `mix phx.server`

Answer (score 2):

This was needed for me as a solution since my issue was that I needed to let [C9.io](http://www.c9.io) dictate the port, for me, adding this code to the `dev.exs` file solved the problem:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
```

and then in the Terminal, I just needed to run the server as normal:

```
mix phoenix.server
```